# I didn't know I had to fast ramadan what do i do?

Tags: ramadan

I didn't know I had to fast, so I missed a ramadan, around a few years ago, what should I do?

Comment: How come you don't know that you had to fast, are you just converting to a Muslim

Comment: Plz inform more about you.

Comment: Why didn't you know you have to fast? Please use the edit link to elaborate and write a clear concise question read [ask].

Comment: I didn't know I was the age that I had to fast